# on behalf profile organization name not showing on pay later receipt

Tags: civimember, contributions, contribution-page, receipts

We are using the on behalf profile, but the organization name isn't showing on the receipt when users use the "Pay Later" option.  The organization name is under "Member" and the receipt is only displaying fields marked as "Contact"